# why does my print function (in multiprocessing) print nothing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder

why does my print function (in python multiprocess) print nothing?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import os, time, random


def write(q):
    print('Process to write: %s' % os.getpid())
    for value in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
        print('Put %s to queue...' % value)
        q.put(value)
        time.sleep(random.random())


def read(q):
    print('Process to read: %s' % os.getpid())
    while True:
        value = q.get(True)
        print('Get %s from queue.' % value)

if __name__=='__main__':

    q = Queue()
    pw = Process(target=write, args=(q,))
    pr = Process(target=read, args=(q,))

    pw.start()
    print('start')

    pr.start()

    pw.join()

    pr.terminate()
    print('end')
```

I run it on spyder (windows 10 system).

My result on IPython console of Spyder:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/programs/crawl/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/programs/crawl')
start
end
```

Result on Python console of Spyder:

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/programs/crawl/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/programs/crawl')
start
Process to write: 12824
Put A to queue...
Put B to queue...
Put C to queue...
end
```

It is really weird. The results are different, but both are not what I want.

Could anyone help me find where is the problem in my program. Thanks a lot

Comment: It prints properly.

Comment: Can you share some more information? Does none of your `print()` statements produce any output? Does your code terminate without any errors?

Comment: I've had trouble with print statements in threads before. Have you tried `print('Process to write: %s' % os.getpid(), flush=True)`?

Comment: it prints ok like this: `start, Process to write: 3956, Put A to queue..., Process to read: 4144, Get A from queue., Put B to queue..., Get B from queue., Put C to queue..., Get C from queue., end` Whats your problem. are you using terminal?

Comment: My result only has "start" and "end" which are in the mainprocess. And there is no error information.   P.S.　I run it on IPython console of Spyder (win 10).

Comment: The `subprocess` and `multiprocessing` modules are two different things. Conflating them (as using the former in the title when the question is about the latter) is not helpful.

Comment: @D.., have you evaluated whether the answer given in the proposed duplicate fixes your problem?

Comment: @Xingzhou Liu, it does work on the Python console of Spyder if I and **sys.stdout.flush()** after print function. But it still doesn't work on IPython console of Spyder.

Comment: Got it, withdrawn

Comment: You wait for `write` to put things into the queue. You don't wait for `read` to take anything out.

Comment: @orangeInk   Did you run your program on IPython？It still doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2357112   Do you mean I have a `time.sleep()` function in `write` , but `read` has none? I've tried it. It doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

The multiprocessing module uses *fork* to spawn child processes for parallelism.  Windows does not implement *fork*, and Python emulation of it on Windows is incomplete.  One of the missing effects is that `stdout` (used by `print()`) is not inherited by the child processes.  Rather, child processes use the default `stdout`.

This works fine in a command window because it uses default `stdout`.  This shows nothing in Spyder because a different pipe is used for output to the Spyder IPython console window.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629103/simple-python-multiprocessing-function-in-spyder-doesnt-output-results) ("Simple Multiprocessing function in Spyder doesn't output results") and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632397/5787967) for additional details and potential mitigations.