# multiprocessing doesn't run on my machine

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying o solve a task of multiprocessing in Python.

I can achieve his task with he help of `multiprocess` module but can't apply the same with `multiprocessing` module. I have to apply with multiprocessing module cause I need to use `freeze_support()`.

First I thought that the issue is with my code and post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61564223/multiprocess-module-vs-multiprocessing-module), which haven't received any answers yet. Then I thought to run a toy example of applying `multiprocessing` module to see whether I can figure out why multiprocessing doesn't run on my system. So I ran this code which I got from [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/).

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def cpu_bound(number):
    return sum(i * i for i in range(number))


def find_sums(numbers):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(cpu_bound, numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [5_000_000 + x for x in range(20)]

start_time = time.time()
find_sums(numbers)
duration = time.time() - start_time
print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

It seems that `multiprocessing` module doesn't run on my machine, cause this toy example won't run on my system either.

When I apply `multiprocess` module on this toy example, the results showed up in no time with utilizing all of my cores.

So I am wondering if the issue is with a specific configuration on my system or is there any equivalent of `freeze_support()` in `multiprocess` module?

By saying "this module won't run on my system", I mean that processes have spawned but the cpu won't go up and it seems that nothing is going on... after almost 10 minutes I manually terminate the run. But with multiprocess module the code completed in under 1 minute.

Thanks in advance.

PS: My machine has 4 cores.

Comment: try putting everything below `numbers = ...` into the `if` statement

Comment: define "this toy example won't run on my system"?

Comment: How do you mean, "doesn't run on my machine"? Can you paste the error trace?

Comment: @njzk2 I mean that processes have spawned but the cpu won't go up and it seems that nothing is going on... after almost 10 minutes I manually terminate the run. But with multiprocess module the code completed in under 1 minute.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I edited my post to clarify it.

Comment: what does `os.cpu_count()` returns on your machine?

Comment: @njzk2 my machine has 4 cores.

Comment: You need to put all the bottom code block in the  `if __name__` block...

Comment: @mpy but is that actually what `os.cpu_count()` returns?

Comment: @njzk2 yes it is.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The issue has nothing to do with the "if __name__" block... I could not run the code from within the Spyder... I ran it perfectly from windows command prompt without any change in my code and closing this post was completely wrong.

Comment: Your code is broken on windows so it's a reasonable assumption that the problem was due to your inadequate use of copy-paste from the tutorial you linked. Closing your question was completely right. That being said since you now know the issue was something else (which you haven't mentioned for a week even though I left an explicit comment) I'll reopen it, simple as that. You should either delete the question or leave a self-answer explaining the issue.

Comment: Just to be clear: did you actually fix the `if __name__` block and try again on spyder?

Comment: Your code runs in 2.5 sec on my machine with spyder 4.1, python 3.8, ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @CKM it's bound to work on ubuntu. The question used to be duped to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222534/python-multiprocessing-on-windows-if-name-main

Comment: @AndrasDeak I really found the solution after one week of struggling. I was about to answer my own question but it was closed... and I have also tried move everything under the "if __name__" block, but that also didn't work. I would post the behavior of the Spyder on my system if I could video screen....Anyway thanks for reopening...

Comment: No worries, closing is not an end, it's a means to making questions answerable. I could've reopened the moment you verified that the `__name__` block wasn't it. Unfortunately spyder has quite a few surprising quirks, none for the better.

Answer (score 0):

OK after almost one week of struggling, I found out that the issue was neither my system nor the `"if __name__"` block. The problem was with my IDE `Spyder`.

I ran the code from the windows command prompt and both [the toy example](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/) and my own real code ran perfectly. I really don't understand why, however I managed to eventually run my script.

I would be happy if others had this similar issue and share their experience...

Comment: I've come across an older post that says [spyder's ipython and multiprocessing don't play nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078722/no-multiprocessing-print-outputs-spyder)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for mentioning.... seems that that I'm not alone ;)