# Python Multiprocessing error: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'task' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder

I'm using spyder 5.1.5 and I am trying to follow along with the very first example on a website.  I'm getting the error:

```py
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'task' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

`task` is a function that I define.

Full example code:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def task(num):
    print("a",num)
    time.sleep(2)
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    for i in range(10):
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task,args=(i,))
       p.start()
```

Comment: In general, multiprocessing doesn't work in browsers or web sites.  There has to be a file containing `task` that's in the same file of the multiprocessing statement.  Your code above works perfectly when copied to a file

Comment: If you are running in an environment such as Jupyter Notebook or iPython, then you must put function `task` in a separate file, e.g. *task.py*, and then import the function, e.g. `from task import task`.

Comment: Go into spyder settings, and under the "Run" menu: select "Execute in an external system terminal". Then after saving the file, execute it by pressing F5 or by using the "Run File" button. Don't run individual cells or selections of code.

Comment: Also you it would probably be a good idea to wait  in the main process for the children to finish. As it stands it "should" work because python attempts to cleanup any existing children by `join`ing them before shutdown, but it's not a good idea to rely on auto-cleanup. You should always explicitly cleanup after resources like open files, running threads, child processes, etc.

Comment: @DanielWalker Did Booboo's suggestion not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

As per Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers):

> **Note:** Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__`
> module be importable by the children. This is covered in [Programming
> guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming), however, it is worth pointing out here. This means that some
> examples, such as the [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) examples will not work
> in the interactive interpreter.

Spyder uses IPython console, allowing you to execute commands and interact with data inside [IPython](https://ipython.org/) interpreters. However, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099756) by a Spyder maintainer:
*"Multiprocessing doesn't work well on Windows in Spyder's IPython console."*

### Option 1

Update your Spyder software, as you are using an old - **5.1.5** as you mentioned - version. However, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099756), *"since our **5.2.0** version (released in November 2021), prints generated while running multiprocessing code are captured and displayed in the IPython console for all operating systems"*.

### Option 2

Change the console settings to run your code using an external terminal instead. To do that, please go to:
`Run` > `Configuration per file...` >  `Execute in an external system terminal` (under console).

### Option 3

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383397), you could write your function into a separate file and import it into your script. For instance:

**tasks.py**

```
import time

def task(num):
    print("a",num)
    time.sleep(2)
```

**main.py**

```
import multiprocessing
from tasks import task

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    for i in range(10):
       p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task,args=(i,))
       p.start()
```