# Python multiprocessing.Process() got different behavior in cmd console and spyder

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder

So this is a code snippet from python doc to demonstrate multiprocessing module.
I opened a empty file 'multi_process_test.py' and typed in these code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

And the weird part is if I run it under Spyder, the program prints nothing, but if I run the source code in powershell env by 'python multi_process_test.py', the console will prints 'hello bob' as expected, can s.b. help to explain why this happen? Or any hint to resolve this difference.

Appreciated for your help.

Comment: Reason for that is because Spyder will automatically open an IPython console on a single core. Because of that, multithreading is not possible in Spyder.

Comment: hmm..so the multiprocessing module won't be able execute if there is only one core?  Or just constrained by the Spyder setup. @1313e

Comment: Multiprocessing requires that you can spawn multiple processes. You need access to multiple threads in order to do so. In an IPython console, you only have access to those that the console has access to, which are the ones it is running on.

Comment: @1313e, please stop spreading false rumors about Spyder. It's completely false what you said.

Comment: @leolee, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29629103/438386) to understand how to fix your problem.

Comment: @leolee, by the way, `multiprocessing` is not the best way to parallelize your code on Windows. You should consider other options like `ipyparallel` or `joblib`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Oh...thank you for your answer, and thank you for your contributions to  Spyder, haha.