# python multiprocessing issue in windows and spyder

Tags: python, spyder, python-multiprocessing

I have a project for my college regarding multiprocessing in python.For my python projects I use spyder in windows.  Therefore im trying to run a very trivial multi - processing code in spyder but every time i run it spyder console freezes and never finishes. This is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import multiprocessing

def f(i):
    return i+1

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    result = pool.map(f, range(4))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() #you need this in windows
    main()
```

I have noticed this is a common issue with multi-proccesing and the lack of fork in windows, therefore i took into account the paragraph 16.6.3.2. Windows in  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows .

I also avoided printing from my child process as stated here:[Simple Python Multiprocessing function doesn't output results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629103/simple-python-multiprocessing-function-doesnt-output-results) and instead used return.

My code works if i run it from a unix terminal, but i'm mainly using windows for my python projects.
Is there a workaround for this issue in windows?

Comment: Have you tried running from Windows Command Prompt?  Or using Python version 3? I tried running your code from Windows 10 Command Prompt, Python version 3 and it works.

Comment: I have and it works fine. Im trying to find a solution or a workaround for the spyder though. After some research i found out that it is a live intepreter issue. But i guess not using spyder for multi processing isnt exactly a programming answer.

Comment: for what it's worth, I can run your code just fine on win7, py2.7, spyder 3.1.3 in its ipython interpreter

Comment: @kevinsa5  i am on win10,python2.7,spyder 3.2.6 and the issue persists. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078722/no-multiprocessing-print-outputs-spyder?noredirect=1&lq=1)  it is stated by a spyder maintainer that indeed multiprocessing doesn't work well on Windows in Spyder's IPython console

Comment: @vtsimp could you please open an Issue about your problem on Spyder's GitHub repo. I'll answer your question over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research i understand that there is an issue with interactive interpreters and multiporcessing.

In: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction it is stated that:
**Note**: ... some examples, such as the Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

An older post addressing a similar issue it was answered by a spyder maintainer that indeed multiprocessing doesn't work well on Windows in Spyder's IPython console. ([No multiprocessing print outputs (Spyder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078722/no-multiprocessing-print-outputs-spyder?noredirect=1&lq=1))

*The only workaround i found so far is to use the windows cmd to run the code*